# spring-rabbit 1.7.2+ autorecovery broken?

Tags: scala, spring-rabbit

Is it possible the connection auto recovery is broken as of spring-rabbit 1.7.2 ?

A test of listeners succeed until upgrading spring-rabbit to 1.7.2. The next version, 1.7.3, also fails. The test is simple enough: Start the listener, stop the RabbitMQ server, start the Rabbit MQ server and watch the listener getting messages.

However, strangely enough, the auto recovery does work for 1.7.2 and higher when *not* calling "setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled()". Or calling it with *false*. Which should disable the auto recovery.

The Spring config (in Scala)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(Array("com.foo"))
@EnableRabbit
class AMQPConfig {

  @Bean
  def rabbitListenerContainerFactory: SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory = {
    val factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory())
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1)
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1)
    factory
  }

  @Bean
  def rabbitTemplate(): RabbitTemplate = {
    val template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory())
    template.setRoutingKey("key")
    template.setExchange("xchange")
    template
  }

  @Bean
  def connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory = {
    val factory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost")
    factory.setUsername("foo")
    factory.setPassword("bar")
    factory.setVirtualHost("fooman")
    factory.setPort(5672)
    factory.getRabbitConnectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)
    factory.getRabbitConnectionFactory.setRequestedHeartbeat(120)
    factory
  }
}
```

The listener

```
@Component
class QueueListener {

  @RabbitListener(id = "listen", containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues = Array("q"))
  def onMessage(message: String): Unit = {
    QueueListener.count.incrementAndGet()
    println("GOT MESSAGE: " + message)
  }

}

object QueueListener {
  val count = new AtomicInteger(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring AMQP has had its own recovery mechanism since day 1; it predates auto recovery in the client library by several years.

If you create a `CachingConnectionFactory` with the constructor that takes a preconfigured RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory`, we emit this message...

```
if (rabbitConnectionFactory.isAutomaticRecoveryEnabled()) {
    logger.warn("***\nAutomatic Recovery is Enabled in the provided connection factory;\n"
            + "while Spring AMQP is compatible with this feature, it\n"
            + "prefers to use its own recovery mechanisms; when this option is true, you may receive\n"
            + "'AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException's until the connection is recovered.");
}
```

When you set the option the way you are doing it we, of course, can't detect that and won't emit the message.

In general, the connection will be recovered faster by Spring AMQP (on the sending side), recovery on the consumer side has similar characteristics to the client (with default configuration).

That said, as the log message indicates, using auto recovery shouldn't hurt anything, it will just cause a recovery delay on the producer side.

I have not seen the behavior you describe; perhaps it has something to do with you using Scala, or something else in your environment; a DEBUG log spanning the shutdown/restart and failure to recover would be useful if you really must use the client's auto recovery for some reason.